# using iRODS c++ API

Tags: c++

I intend to put/get file to/from an iRODS server. iRODS provides well documented JAVA and PHP APIs, however I'm looking for a **C/C++** library providing such functions.

Are there libraries or examples of code I could use ?

Comment: I asked basically the same thing on the iRODS mailing list, so [the thread might be interesting for you](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/irod-chat/rA1Z33xaGMc/HnvJgu7LBQAJ).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you've requested, but you might be interested in [Baton](https://github.com/wtsi-npg/baton), which uses the iRODS C API, and has had a lot of work put into it, so you might be able to use it as-is, depending on your use case, rather than writing your own from scratch. Failing that, it provides a lot of examples of using the API.

If you have reasons that you must write your own,  then in 4.x the [the iRODS docs for the C API](https://wiki.irods.org/doxygen_api/html/index.html) are much improved from the earlier 3.3.1 code path.

Good luck and do try the mailing list as a previous commenter mentioned - the developers respond often.